# UIView on top of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subviews

I have been developing an app in which I have a `UIViewController`, to which I have added a `UITableView`. Now I want to add a `UIView` on top of the `tableview` at a fixed position.

I tried the following code, but the `UIView` scrolls along with the `tableView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 100, 50, 50)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [_tableView addSubview:view];
    [_tableView bringSubviewToFront:view];
}
```

How can I prevent the `UIView` from scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` you could try to implement something like "floating view". To do this you should make sure

1. The floating view is always the top most view in the hierarchy
2. The position of the floating view should be updated when the `contentOffset` changes (so that visually it would float on top of other content when the user is scrolling)

You can try something like this (assuming that `floatingHeaderViewCenter` is the initial center of the `floatingView`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.floatingHeaderView.center = CGPointMake(floatingHeaderViewCenter.x + scrollView.contentOffset.x, floatingHeaderViewCenter.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:floatingHeaderView];
}
```

Although you'd better have a view container with two subviews: your tableview and the floating view.

Comment: Actually I want the UIView to appear on top of the TableView in the center position. So I cannot use tableview header and footer.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add the view as a subview of the table view. Instead, the view controller view should be a container for the other views, which, in this case, is a view and a table view. Add both of these as subviews of the view controller view.

Comment: But if I add the second UIView as a subView of the viewController then it hides behind the tableView. I want it to appear above it.

Comment: Are you still using `bringSubviewToFront`?

Comment: like this tableView.superview?.addSubview(newView)

Answer (score 1):

If the view(viewToBringFront) hides behind then you can make it front by adding this line:

```
self.viewToBringFront.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```